# DismHost.exe в папке Temp удалить или что сделать?

Tags: windows, windows-10

В папке Temp переодически появляется папка, в последем случае, **EF4E7D45-B126-4393-8A1D-634E53EC8CCD**. В ней программа **DismHost.exe** и другие файлы. Я искал информацию в Google, но не нашел конкретики, что нужно делать. Удалять или не удалять. Обычно, после появления таких папок, у меня уменьшается размер диска С. Сегодня появилась такая папка, я ее удалил. Размер диска С уменьшился на 2ГБ. Подскажите, если кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой. Спасибо.

Comment: DISM это штатная фигня, которая работает с обновлениями и образами винды. Скорее всего у тебя что-то обновляется в фоне (10-ка же). Попробуй максимально отключить все обновы и посмотреть появляются папки или нет. Ну и если папка удаляется, значит процесс, который её "держал" - завершился и в принципе ничего критичного произойти не должно.

Comment: Уаважаемый don Rumata, спасибо Вам за информацию! После установки Windows, я запустил от имени администратора утилиту Windows Update Blocker. Но через время, DismHost.exe появляется. Хотя теоретически, утилита не должна допускать такого, ведь она остановила все службы обновления.

Comment: Винда с сайта майков или ты любитель сборок типа зверьдвд?

Comment: Windows оригинальная, с сайта Microsoft.

Comment: Должна информация о событии развертывания обновления, установки ПО и т.п. остаться в журналах Windows в интервал времени, совпадающий со временем создания папки. Думаю, отключение Windows Update не влияет на уже запланированные события развертывания ПО в Планировщике. ищите. При полном отсутствии следов, нужно аудит подключить.